# Compare a variable to every element of an array

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to compare a variable to the values that are stored in an array. The values in the array are extracted out from a csv file. If the values of the array are equal to the variable it will print out true.

```
import csv

array=[]

values = csv.reader(open('SampleEEG data Insight-1-30.11.15.17.36.16.csv', 'r'),       
                    delimiter=',',
                    quotechar='|')
for row in values:
    array.append(row[5])

number= 4200

for a in array:
    if number == a:
        print ('True')
print ('False')
```

The code only compares one value in the array and returns a false. How do I compare all the values in the array to the variable?

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#all) function with list comprehensions

```
number = 10
array = [1, 2, 3, 4]

print( all(number == a for a in array) )
# False

array = [10, 10, 10, 10]
print( all(number == a for a in array) )
# True
```

Comment: Hey thank it works! I have another problem, the for loop wont stop so it keep on printing false. Is there a way to stop it from running the loop when it has finish comparing the value in array?

Comment: For first `a in array` which is not equal to `number` the `all` is going to break out due to short circuiting thing, without caring about any subsequent matches. I don't think this is what the OP is asking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `all()` - builtin function

```
all (number == a for a in array)
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I could figure out from your comment, this is probably what you are looking for:

```
array=[]

with open('SampleEEG data Insight-1-30.11.15.17.36.16.csv', 'r') as file:
    lines = [line.split() for line in file.readlines()]


for line in lines:
    try:
        array.append(float(line[5]))
    except ValueError:
        pass

number= 4200

for a in array:
    if number == a:
        print ('True')
print ('Done, all checked')
```

Comment: Hi, if i'd add the csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC, theres an error saying that : ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'title:1' for line 7

Comment: oops! Ok ignore csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC, and note the indentation used: print('True') must be indented as shown. Try that. Also can you show one line of sample text from your csv file, that would be helpful for helping you ;-)

Comment: is something like this 
4136.410156
4136.410156
4141.025391
4149.230469
4153.333008
4153.333008
4152.307617
4148.205078
4147.692383
4158.974121
4168.205078

Comment: @huihan just like that? all numbers and numbers are not separated by commas? As far as I know data elements must be separated by commas in a csv file. Are you sure your file doesn't have comma separating the contents??

Comment: yep, when is read from the csv file, it will be separate by commas.

Comment: @huihan I don't understand. If that's the actual sample from your csv file, the contents are not separated by commas. Try the code I have given. And if the actual file you are reading from doesn't have commas, then how will the contents be separated by commas when it is being read???

Comment: @huihan where have you gone? If you don't actually need the help, why did you post the question in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

Because it is exiting from the loop after it hits the first true value. Use the following code:

```
   for i in array:
        if number == i:
            print ('True')
        else:
            print ('False')
```